# Unable to insert verification code data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert data into mysql database, this is an email registration with verification. The unique random number is not inserting into the database table. Please help me. Thanks a bunch.

```
else {
    $user_confirm = md5(uniqid(rand()));
    echo "$user_confirm";
    //the form has been posted without, so save it
    //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
    //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(
                   user_name, 
                   user_pass, 
                   user_email,
                   user_date,
                   user_level,
                   user_confirm
            )
            VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
                   '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                   NOW(),
                   0, 
                  '$user_confirm'
            )";

    $email = $_POST["user_email"];  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What is the column type for `user_confirm`, as well as the length on the column.

Comment: as a sidenote, you aren't hashing your passwords into db. [Here it Is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) for `mysqli` or `pdo`. As a perk, you might find the parameter passing a little less arcane and error prone than the way you are doing it with a deprecated library `mysql_*`

Comment: How about some error checking such as `mysql_error()` - makes it much easier to work out what is wrong and how to fix.

Comment: user_confirm is INT(11).

Comment: I am using sha1 Drew, and In my database I can see the password is hashed.

Comment: ok lemme check mysql_error() Tristan

Comment: every other information is storing but I am unable to insert this random number.

Comment: The `INT(11)` is not large enough and is the wrong type of field to store your SHA1 ***string***. Check your error logs. You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Same thing with `$user_confirm`, it is a ***string*** (like beba256f79e888013bb34e5a774fe7f9), not an ***INT***.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues: `$user_confirm` is a string (I generated `beba256f79e888013bb34e5a774fe7f9` with your code) and you're trying to store it in a column that is designated for integers (`INT(11)`).

Hashed strings *should* be stored in `TEXT` fields to allow for the size of the strings generated by `md5()` and `sha1()`.

Second, you really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL md5 function returns  a string of 32 hex digits, or NULL if the argument was NULL. Use varchar(32) instead of int(11) for the field.

[Refer to MySQL Document for more info.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

Also, ensure that you are adding quotes to string field correctly.