# Creating login page with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code in which I've been trying to Create a login system with php and MySQL but the if else condition are not working properly, i am giving correct values (which are stored in database) on executing it on the browser, it is displaying Invalid email or password instead of displaying Successful Login.. Here is the Code..

```
<HTML>
<body>

<?php 

$email= $_POST['email']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

  echo "Email:".$email. " <br>";
 echo "Password: ".$password; 

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("log");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE `Email` = '$email' AND `Password` = 

'$password'") or die("I am dead");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row['Email']. " - ". $row['Password'];
    echo "<br />";
}

if ($row['Email'] == $email && $row['Password'] == $password){
echo "Login Successfull" ;
}
else {
echo "<br> Invalid Email or Password";
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. The problem is you are accessing the `$row` array outside the loop.

Comment: Are you storing the password in plain text? In addition to using `mysqli` you also need to escape users inputs to prevent injection attacks

Comment: I wrote this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) up. It is a good blue print for it in mysqli and pdo. Unfortunately the gent was new to databases and it has 50 comments under it. Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `mysqli` as `mysql` is depreciated.

You don't need a loop here. just check with `mysqli_num_rows` like

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  echo "Login Successfull" ;
}else {
  echo "<br> Invalid Email or Password";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't yet have the rep to add this as simply a comment and must therefore leave it as an answer.
You're code, as written, is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.  If you're not familiar with that there are some great videos on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/_jKylhJtPmI) detailing what this means and how to protect your database.  You must sanitize your code.
Best of luck,

Jeremiah