# Registration and login

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Im countering sort of a weird problem at this moment. I made a simple login form, it works halfway thru. You can indeed write your name in and such but once you hit the Submit button, I get some " Undefined index: nameX" symbols eventho I have added the variable for it before the function and such.

This is the content of the sql_connection.sql (well part of it you have to see atleast)

```
/* Registration */
    $nameX = $_POST['name'];

    $query = isRegistered($_POST['name']); //this will check if they are valid or not

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
            if($query == true) {
                echo "Welcome back";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "No accounts found";
        }
    }

function isRegistered($name) {
        global $handler;

        $query = "SELECT ID FROM players WHERE Username= '".$name."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($handler, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is the actual form

```
<div id="login">
            <form action="includes/sql_connection.php" method="get">
                First name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up">
            </form>
        </div>
```

The error

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   C:\wamp\www\php\includes\sql_connection.php on line 101

and the error line (line: 101)

```
$nameX = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: You are using GET but looking for form values in POST

Comment: Aha thanks ! I overlooked that

Comment: how about a password

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/2685/sql-injection-and-prevention#t=201607240136533133613)

Comment: Why fetch, the `num_rows` will already tell you if there was a record.

Comment: I have a `mysqli` routine you can poach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) . It has a decent stub for a mini schema, a form, registration, login, hashed password, password verify, session, and binding parameters. Rather compressed, but I didn't want to write a book.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick observations

Your form triggers a `GET` request, but your code is looking at `POST` inputs. You'll never see anything.  John Conde pointed that out.

You also have a logic flaw

```
$nameX = $_POST['name'];    
$query = isRegistered($_POST['name']);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
```

You're using `$_POST['name']` first, then checking whether it's non-empty later.  You're accessing form inputs first, then checking whether there are any inputs later (with the `isset`).  That will cause your `isRegistered` to be called with undefined variables when there is no form input. This order should be reversed.