# How do I put these 2 queries in SQL terms?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario where upon a person registering a new community I want them to automatically become a member of that community.

I have 3 tables:

`users
id | user_email | user_password | user_name`

`communities
id | name | code | admin`

`community_playes
community_id | player_id`

Upon the community being created I immediately need to run the following MySQL queries so that person becomes a member of said community:

1) To get community_id from table communities where admin = email and put into table community_players, community_id

2) To get id from table users where user_email = email and put into table community_players, player_id

I already have `email` as a variable.

My aim is to populate the community_players table with a new record containing the id of the user, and the community_id of the newly created community.

What would be the SQL statement for this? I have no experience in SQL.

Comment: You use [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))s.

Comment: It would help us (and yourself) if you included the expected output you want, or at least a sample of that.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: a trigger perhaps. I suggest spending a few days in mysql tutorials. Also hash your password like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) or the PDO link at the bottom of it