# PHP, MySQL Login Issue After Adding More Table Columns/Inputs

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I started out using just "Name" "Email" "Password"  and the login with the email and password worked fine. Now I have 11 columns in the table --including the id-- and the login will not work. I am testing this out in my local "XAMPP" server with MySQL. I can register okay but I keep getting the "Incorrect User Name or Password" message when logging in. Of course, I am using the correct ones. I have tried clearing my browser, recreating the table, and rebooting the machine. My login page remains the same --as it was before adding more table columns/inputs-- and is for using the email address and password from the table in the database. There is no issue with dbconnect.php connecting. I suspect the problem is in the if statement that will produce :"Incorrect User Name or Password!!!" when one or the other does not match. Can anyone see a reason why the login keeps giving me the error message "Incorrrect...etc"?? Perhaps adding all the new inputs/columns requires something different for logging in from what I have here?
---THANKS

___Begin login.php________________________________________

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="") {
    header("Location: alreadyloggedin.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM blogusers WHERE email = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: index-blog.php");
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect User Name or Password!!!";
    }
}
?>


<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="container blog-container"><!-- Begin Blog Container-->
                <div class="row"><!-- Begin Blog Row -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 blog-left-column" style="padding: 0px;"><!-- Begin Blog Content Div (Left Column) -->
                        <div class="blog-header"><!-- Begin Blog Content Header -->
                            <p><g16 class="blog-header-text">THE DATABASE DRIVEN BLOG BY ROBERT</g16></p>
                        </div><!-- End Blog Content Header -->
                        <div class="blog-content"><!-- Begin - Main blog content in this div -->

                            <div class="form-reg"><!-- Begin div to contain form -->
            <table width="50%" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="">
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="legend-01"><g16>Please Login</g16></legend>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Enter Your Email</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" required class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>   
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Password</g14></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                    <td>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr><td>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">    
                        <g14>New User? <a href="register.php">Sign Up Here</a></g14>
                    </div>
                 </td></tr>
            </table>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>

            </div><!-- End div to contain form -->
                            <br><br><br><br>

                        </div><!-- End - Main blog content in this div -->
                        <div class="blog-header" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 1px;"><!-- Begin Blog Content Footer -->
                          <p><g16 class="blog-header-text"><hr></g16></p>
                        </div><!-- End Blog Content Footer -->
                    </div><!-- End Blog Content Div (Left Column) -->
                    <!-- End of Body -->
<?php include('side-comments.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

___End login.php________________________________________

___Begin register.php________________________________________

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: logout2register.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zip']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);

    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$first_name)) {
        $error = true;
        $first_name_error = "Name must contain only letters";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$last_name)) {
        $error = true;
        $last_name_error = "Name must contain only letters";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i",$address)) {
        $error = true;
        $address_error = "Address can contain only letters, numbers, dash";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$city)) {
        $error = true;
        $city_error = "City must contain only letters";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$state)) {
        $error = true;
        $state_error = "State must contain only letters";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]+$/",$zip)) {
        $error = true;
        $zip_error = "Zip must contain only numbers";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 .\-]+$/i",$phone)) {
        $error = true;
        $phone_error = "Phone can contain numbers and dashs or periods x12";
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = true;
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-0-9 ]+$/",$user_name)) {
        $error = true;
        $user_name_error = "User name can contain only letters and numbers";
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO blogusers(first_name,last_name,address,city,state,zip,phone,email,user_name,password) VALUES('" . $first_name . "', '" . $last_name . "', '" . $address . "', '" . $city . "', '" . $state . "', '" . $zip . "', '" . $phone . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $user_name . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
            $successmsg = "Thank You for Regestering!! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div class="container blog-container"><!-- Begin Blog Container-->
                <div class="row"><!-- Begin Blog Row -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 blog-left-column" style="padding: 0px;"><!-- Begin Blog Content Div (Left Column) -->
                        <div class="blog-header"><!-- Begin Blog Content Header -->
                            <p><g16 class="blog-header-text">THE DATABASE DRIVEN BLOG BY ROBERT</g16></p>
                        </div><!-- End Blog Content Header -->
                        <div class="blog-content"><!-- Begin - Main blog content in this div -->

                            <div class="form-reg" style="width: 100%;"><!-- Begin div to contain form -->
            <table width="40%" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="">
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="legend-01"><g16>Registration</g16></legend>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>First Name</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $first_name; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($first_name_error)) echo $first_name_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Last Name</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $last_name; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($last_name_error)) echo $last_name_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Address</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Your Address" required value="<?php if($error) echo $address; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($address_error)) echo $address_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>City</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Your City" required value="<?php if($error) echo $city; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($city_error)) echo $city_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>State</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="state" maxlength="2" placeholder="2 Letters" required value="<?php if($error) echo $state; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($state_error)) echo $state_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Zip</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" length="5" placeholder="5 Numbers" required value="<?php if($error) echo $zip; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($zip_error)) echo $zip_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Phone Number</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" max-length="12" placeholder="Area & Number Dash or Dot Ok" required value="<?php if($error) echo $zip; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($phone_error)) echo $phone_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>   
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Email</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter a Valid Email" required value="<?php if($error) echo $email; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>   
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>User Name</g14></label>
                        <input type="text" name="user_name" min-length="5" min-length="15" placeholder="5 to 15 Characters" required value="<?php if($error) echo $user_name; ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($user_name_error)) echo $user_name_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Password</g14></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" min-length="6" maxlength="15" placeholder="6 to 15 Chracters" required class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <label for="name"><g14>Confirm Password</g14></label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr><td><div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;"><g14>Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login Here</g14></a></div></td></tr>
            </table>
            <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>

            </div><!-- End div to contain form -->
                            <br><br><br><br>

                        </div><!-- End - Main blog content in this div -->
                        <div class="blog-header" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 1px;"><!-- Begin Blog Content Footer -->
                          <p><g16 class="blog-header-text"><hr></g16></p>
                        </div><!-- End Blog Content Footer -->
                    </div><!-- End Blog Content Div (Left Column) -->
                    <!-- End of Body -->
<?php include('side-comments.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

___End register.php________________________________________

***This is from the Table Export, phpMyAdmin***

```
    CREATE TABLE `blogusers` (
      `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `phone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `user_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(15) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

___Thank You________________________________________

Comment: Were you md5ing the whole time? I think `15` is too short.

Comment: You are not using a safe password_verify mechanism (yours is subject to Timing attacks). So hopefully no one takes this md5 hash approach and implements it. See this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) of mine that uses parameter bindings and modern hash with verify (in `mysqli` plus a link to a `PDO` version)

Comment: Yes... you were exactly right! It took a minute for that issue/solution to sink in. Of course, I had to realize that the encryption required the 32 character places in the table to be stored. Thanks. Also, I will need to learn more about security...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 processes an arbitrary-length message into a fixed-length output of 128 bits, typically represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal digits. `md5($password)` Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.

You used `password` length `varchar(15)` like bellow:

```
`password` varchar(15) NOT NULL
```

it should be minimum length 32 or more then like bellow

```
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I agree. This job is for academic purposes. I would have allowed at least 50. That's just the number (15) the instructor indicated. I am trying to learn this stuff. The code for logging in worked fine before I added 7 more inputs.

Comment: Oh, okay! I will try changing the password to varchar(32) and see if that makes the difference. I checked the school server where my previous version --with only a 4 column table-- and I was using varchar(50) for the password.

Comment: !!!<That's It>!!! You hit it right on the money! I knew the md5 was encrypting the password, but had no thought about accommodating the 32 characters in the table... just whatever the user would input. I gave it (50) and there are 32 characters in there for the password. THANK YOU!!

Comment: i thinks now you can't able to upvote. Need to your reputation up 15 for upvote.