# PDO/mysql UPDATE query doesn't do anything or display errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The code that starts on line 49 is doing absolutely nothing. I have tried to display PHP errors, used try and catch with the PDO set attributes etc, which also didn't display an error.

The code worked before in `mysqli` when I was using the mysql extension to connect but I'm currently in the process of converting the entire application to `PDO`.

```
    <?php 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
//mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if(!isset($_SESSION['eid'])){ header("Location: index.php"); } else {

require('dbconn.php');
$sessionuser = $_SESSION['eid'];
$messageid = $_GET['id'];

try{
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = :messageid"; 
$rs_result1 = $db->prepare($sql);
$rs_result1->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
$rs_result1->execute();
$result1 = $rs_result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$senderid = $result1['eidfrom'];
$recid = $result1['eidto'];

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE eid = :senderid";
$rs_result2 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$rs_result2->bindParam(":senderid", $senderid);
$rs_result2->execute();
$result2 = $rs_result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE eid = :recid";
$rs_result3 = $db->prepare($sql2);
$rs_result3->bindParam(":recid", $recid);
$rs_result3->execute();
$result3 = $rs_result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


          echo "<table>";
          echo "<tr><td>To: </td> <td>".$result3['fname']." ".$result3['lname']."</td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>From: </td> <td>". $result2['fname'] ." ".$result2['lname']."</td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Date: </td><td> ". date("l, jS F Y H:i:s", strtotime($result1['date']))."<br /> </td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Subject: </td><td>".$result1['subject']."</td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><img src =\"images/newssplit.gif\"></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Message: </td><td>". $result1['body']." </td></tr>";
          echo "</table>";

          //line 49 below
          if($sessionuser == $senderid) { 
            $sql3 = "UPDATE `messages` SET `reads`='1' WHERE `id`= :messageid";
            $result4 = $db->prepare($sql3);
            $result4->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
            $result4->execute();

             } else {
                    $sql4 = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read`='1' WHERE `id`= :messageid";
                    $result5 = $db->prepare($sql4);
                    $result5->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
                    $result5->execute();
                    }

} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    }
}
?>
```

To say the least I am stuck!  I've read many a post on here with people having the same issues, and I don't see anything wrong with the code.  **What am I missing?**

EDIT: So far I have checked the schema to ensure that my fields to actually exist, tried using query(), tried using standard variables rather than bindParam placeholders, The variable $messageid definitely has a value at that stage, as I test printed $sql3 after replacing :messageid with $messageid.  I have posted some related files and the export of the schema in a zip [ZIP](http://www.adamcopley.xyz/PDOupdateproblem.zip). Haven't come to a solution yet, very stuck on this, as the UPDATE query on line 42 of inbox.php works just fine.

EDIT2: Code above updated with safer select queries, schema has been updated with correct data types and indexes cleaned up. But still what's now on Line 49 will not update the value in messages, OR return an error.

EDIT::SOLVED:

The problem wasn't my query, but my if statement. I hadn't fully tested the functionality of the statement and the queries. What I was doing was testing the queries on a message to and from the same user. An eventuality which I hadn't prepared my if statement for (as it happens the statement and queries combined were working all along for normal user 1 to user 2 and vice versa messages).  Here's how I got it to work.

```
if($sessionuser == $senderid && $sessionuser == $recid) { 

        $result4 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `messages` SET `read_s`='1', `read_`='1' WHERE `id`= :messageid");
        $result4->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
        $result4->execute();

         } elseif($sessionuser == $senderid) {

                $result5 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `messages` SET `read_s`='1' WHERE `id`= :messageid");
                $result5->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
                $result5->execute();
                } else {

                $result6 = $db->prepare("UPDATE `messages` SET `read_`='1' WHERE `id`= :messageid");
                $result6->bindParam(":messageid", $messageid);
                $result6->execute();
                }
```

I changed the column headers from reads and read, to underscored after reading something about reserved words. But then also found it that it actually didn't matter.   Thanks for the help everyone!!! The other notes and feedback that I got regarding the schema etc have helped me learn some good practice!! TYTY

Comment: what happens when you intentionally break the code ? (i.e. `require('blah');` at the top of the file), do you get any error message displayed ?

Comment: You need to use prepared statements for the values in those select.

Comment: Why do you use placeholders in your `UPDATE` queries, but not your `SELECT` queries?

Comment: Try adding spaces between `=:` (`= :`) as some times `id =:messageid` does not mean the same thing as `id = :messageid`

Comment: Do you really have columns `reads` and `read`?

Comment: one last comment - there is no need to do 3 queries at the top to get the message, sender and receiver rows. This can all be done in 1 query using a  `JOIN`

Comment: I added the bindparam placeholders for the update query because it wasn't working like my SELECT queries are, so would try another method.. --   (answers other question,  my select queries are working fine with standard variables? why is this wrong?) - yes 'reads'  and 'read' are both correct field names.

Comment: I've tried adding spaces before the :messageid  and this didn't change anything.

Comment: if you are willing to post all related php files (just the lines necessary) and schema, we can solve this. By the way, do you have something against error reporting and try/catch blocks?

Comment: [PDOupdateproblem.zip](http://www.adamcopley.xyz/PDOupdateproblem.zip)  -   In this file is the above file,  an export of the schema, and other files which use the same tables and similar queries.  I note that in my select queries, I didn't use :parameter placeholders, the standard variables just worked. I'm new to PDO and currently converting the site to it so am not sure whether this is supposed to work or not or is bad practice.  Also in inbox.php,  the update query which loops through checkboxes to change a value is fine.

Comment: Your `SELECT` queries are an invitation to disaster! Always use prepared statements with named placeholders or `?`. It's worth mentioning that `PDOStatement::execute()` can accept your parameters, which saves the call to `PDOStatement::bindParams()`. Tried turning on query logging in mysql?

Comment: to clarify, you mean that they are prone to SQL injection because of the $_GET variables. --  so basically, if I'm using $_POST or GET values within the query i should always use a prepared statement with placeholders/parameters. Thanks, I'll implement that, right away on my select statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your provided zip file in comments

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(50) NOT NULL,   -- why not date datatype?
  `sdate` varchar(50) NOT NULL, -- why not date datatype?
  `address1` text NOT NULL,
  `address2` text NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,    -- why text?
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  -- I can help you solve this next
  `depid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userlevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blocked` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),  -- makes sense
  UNIQUE KEY `eid` (`eid`)  -- why a duplicate key (as PK) ?  you already have it covered
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
truncate table employees;

insert employees(fname,lname,dob,sdate,address1,address2,city,postcode,telephone,mobile,email,password,depid,userlevel,blocked) values
('Frank','Smith','dob','sdate','addr1','addr2','c','p','t','m','e','p',1,2,0);
insert employees(fname,lname,dob,sdate,address1,address2,city,postcode,telephone,mobile,email,password,depid,userlevel,blocked) values
('Sally','Jacobs','dob','sdate','addr1','addr2','c','p','t','m','e','p',1,2,0);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eidto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eidfrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reads` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inbox` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sentbox` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` text NOT NULL,  -- why a text datatype? was it gonna be huge?
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  -- why this data type?
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),       -- makes sense
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),   -- why this dupe?
  KEY `id_2` (`id`)         -- why?
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

insert messages(eidto,eidfrom,`read`,`reads`,inbox,sentbox,subject,body,`date`) values
(1,2,1,1,1,1,'subject','body','thedatething');
```

### inbox.php

```
<?php 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
//mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start();
//$sessionuser = $_SESSION['eid'];
$sessionuser = 1;
require('dbconn.php');

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   // line added
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);       // line added

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
            $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
        } 
        else{ 
            $page=1; 
        }; 

        $start_from = ($page-1) * 10; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE eidto = $sessionuser AND inbox = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start_from, 10"; 
        echo $sql;
        $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE eidto = $sessionuser AND inbox = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start_from, 10"; 
        $rs_result = $db->query($sql);
        $count = $db->query($sql2)->fetchColumn();

        echo "<h3>Inbox</h3>";
        echo "<form action='".$PHP_SELF."' method='post'><table><tr><b><td>#</td><td>From</td><td>Subject</td></b></tr>";
        while ($row = $rs_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
            $senderid = $row['eidfrom'];
            echo "<br>".$senderid;
            $messageid = $row['id'];
            $result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE eid = $senderid");
            $row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row['read'] == 0) {
                echo "<tr> <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$row['id']."' id='checkbox[]'></td>";
                echo "<td><b>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</b></td>";
                echo "<td><b><u><a href='usercp.php?action=messages&f=message&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['subject']."</a></u></b></td></tr>";
            } else {
                echo "<tr> <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$row['id']."' id='checkbox[]'></td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='usercp.php?action=messages&f=message&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['subject']."</a></td></tr>";
            }
        }; 
        echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='delete' value='Delete'></table></form>";

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
                $sql = "UPDATE `messages` SET `inbox`='0' WHERE `id`='$del_id'";
                $result = $db->prepare($sql);
                $result->execute();
            }

            if($result){
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=usercp.php?action=messages&f=inbox\">";
            }
        } 

        // NEED TO MODIFY CODE BELOW SO THAT PREVIOUS LINK DOESN'T LINK TO PAGE 0 WHEN ON PAGE 1
        // AND NEXT DISAPPEARS WHEN ON LAST PAGE WITH RECORDS
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE eidto = $sessionuser AND inbox = 1"; 
        $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE eidto = $sessionuser AND inbox = 1";
        $rs_result = $db->query($sql);
        $rows = $db->query($sql2)->fetchColumn();

        if($rows > 10) {
            $total_pages = ceil($rows / 10); 
            echo "<a href='usercp.php?action=messages&f=inbox&page=".($page-1)."'>Previous</a>";
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                        echo "<a href='usercp.php?action=messages&f=inbox&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
            };  echo "<a href='usercp.php?action=messages&f=inbox&page=".($page+1)."'>Next</a>";
        } else { } 
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
    }
?>
```

Check for errors. You had a typo on **fetchColumn**, something error reporting told me.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**The Op has said he is re-writing his code to PDO.** As such,

- You need to switch to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for parameter passing to protect against SQL Injection attacks.

By the way, above line and color poached from [Fred's great PHP Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)

Note that I added the `try/catch` block, and a PDO connection exception attribute to support it.

Here is a checklist of things to cleanup:

- Move your GETS toward $_POST due to url caching security concerns, and size limitations.
- If you haven't, look into hashing and password_verify. Here is [An Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556010/) I wrote.
- Clean up the datatypes and indexes. Comments are seen in your schema.
- Move to safe prepared statements as mentioned above.

So, as for functionality given here, the fake data I inserted appears, and the delete works. I am sure you can take it from here.

### Edit

Best practice is to choose column names that are not [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). The ones in that list with an `(R)` next to them. The use of back-ticks around all column names in queries is a safeguard against query failure in that regard.

As far as your question of why I back-ticked some and not others. It was 3am, those were showing up as red in my query editor, and I was being lazy in not back-ticking all of them.

Comment: No you don't need PDO, mysqli is perfectly capable of escaping text, using prepared statements, and protect against sql injection attacks..

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of that @hanshenrik (kidding of course). He currently is not doing prepares. There are those that have shown lessor libraries capable. They happen to be deprecated. The OP is saying he is moving toward PDO and now using it. I am saying do PDO with **prepares**. Read the context of the question

Comment: hanshenrik I've decided to go for PDO, due to it's database portability and will more than likely write all php/database code using PDO, unless I have a specific reason not to.  @Drew, thanks for tips on what you analyzed, I will look at it, and definitely implement.    What about the UPDATE query in message.php?  that's the one that's not updating, or showing errors when I did add a try catch block with pdo exceptions. - What that's supposed to do is change the value of read or reads so that I can have a 'You have x unread messages' notification.

Comment: Just a quick one too, how come in insert query at the bottom of the schema you quoted did you use ticks on `read` `reads` and `date`, and not any of the others? Is there a significance of the ticks?

Comment: @Drew Data types and indexes cleaned up - check, move to safe prepared statements, check, I can't use password_verify because the webhost php version is OOD, I have always used md5 though, so it's not just plain text. -  looking at your login function did however help me clean mine up and remove a couple of unneccessary lines. So thanks!  - still can't get the update on message.php to work though :@:@

Comment: I will take a look when I get a chance. Spend a little more time on it. Then post another xyz site zip ref with your latest as I have a few things to do