# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql

this is my code .! i dont know why is it occuring !
 I have seen the previous Answers but i am unable to get a solution for this!
and when i insert data to tables mannually it is duplicating itself.

so any help would be apprecieted !

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
    LOGIN
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=''  method='post'>

        <table>
            <tr>

                <td>
            <p>USWERNAME </br><input type="text" name="username"/></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><p>PASSWORD </br> <input type="password" name="password"/></p></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><p>LOGIN</br> <input type="submit" name="submit"/></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </form>
<?php
include ('include/db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

   $usera=$_POST['username'];
 $passa=$_POST['password'];



  if(!$query=mysql_query("select from admin_login where u_user='$usera' AND u_pass='$passa'"))
  {
      echo mysql_error();
  }

}



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: select *what* from admin_login ...

Comment: Also, you are storing your passwords as clear text. Get off of `mysql_` as clearly you are close to being Day 1 with it all. And get into [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556010)  <---- hashed password example

Comment: Voting to close as Typo, of no benefit to future readers. Then onto delete.

Comment: @drew: indeed its my bad !!

Answer (score 1):

**You have an syntax error here**

```
select from admin_login where u_user='$usera' AND u_pass='$passa'
```

Your syntax like

```
select fieldsname from table_namewhere u_user='$usera' AND u_pass='$passa'
```